# Restore Postgres database schema from *.sql file via pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pgadmin, database-restore

I have several *.sql dump files that I would like to restore to a newly created database 'spatial_db'. I know that I can restore them via command line:
 `psql -U username -h 127.0.0.1 -d spatial_db -f path/to/dump/file.sql`
Is there a way to restore the *.sql file(s) via pgAdmin as with *.backup files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Create the new db `spatial_db`.
- Select the created db and go to `Menu->Plugins->PSQL Console`
- Type the command to import the db `\i /path/to/file.sql`

Also if it is a small file you can open it in editor and execute the sql statements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused. I have PGAdmin4 , I have created a new empty database, but when I select it, I don't see an option that says Menu anywhere. If I look at the right click menu, it doesn't have an option called 'Plugins'. What am I missing here ?

Comment: This answer is for PGAdminIII

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon what if the file is in the .bak format. I am using pgadmin 3. Would this still work?